# Preserving aspect ratio when using torch's image.display

Tags: image, qt, lua, window, torch

I have the following very simple script written in lua. I am running it with qlua.

`require "image"
input_image = image.load(arg[1])
image.display{image = input_image}`

If the image is large the qt window simply takes the whole screen, which also stretches the image to fit the screen.

I can't figure out a way to keep this from happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is large, resize it down to what you can configure as "Max height/Max width", while preserving the aspect ratio.

Sample code:

```
maxSize = 480
-- find the smaller dimension, and resize it to maxSize (while keeping aspect ratio)
local iW = input:size(3)
local iH = input:size(2)
if iW < iH then
   input = image.scale(input, maxSize, maxSize * iH / iW)
else
   input = image.scale(input, maxSize * iW / iH, maxSize)
end
```

Comment: Cool. A few questions. 1) Is there a way to detect how big a window I can get away with on the current screen? I would rather do this in a general way. 2) If I don't want to degrade image quality  (I believe it's possible to zoom in and out) do you think I could just use the zoom parameter on the image.display function with similar logic?